# Adding a second frametitle separated from the first in an mdframed environment

Tags: mdframed

Could you help me in adding a second frametitle into the `mdframed` environment? It's for the citation and it should be something like 15pt / 20pt further to the right than the first title of the definition. So in the following code there should be something like this

```
\begin{df}[mytitle = {Pythagoraen Theorem}{\cite[page 6]{test}}]
This is a definition.
\end{df}
```

I need to add something into the makeatother environment, I assume. But I don't know exactly how to do it. Could you please help me?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{mydef}[chapter]
\renewcommand\themydef{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{mydef}}

\makeatletter
    \def\mdf@mytitle{}
    \define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
      \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}

    \mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}

    \tikzset{
    excursus line/.style={%
    line width=2pt,
draw=gray!40,
rounded corners=2ex,
},
excursus head/.style={%
fill=white,
font=\bfseries\sffamily,
text=blue!80,
anchor=base west,
},
}
\mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
extra={\stepcounter{mydef}},%
singleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
\path [excursus line]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
($(Q)+(30em,0ex)$);
%\node at ($(M)$) {M};
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef\space(\mdf@mytitle):};
\fi},
firstextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,-to]
(O) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-2pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef\space(\mdf@mytitle):};
\fi},
secondextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,round cap-]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
middleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow]
(O) -- (Q);},
middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
hidealllines=true,topline=true,
innertopmargin=0.5ex,
innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innerleftmargin=2ex,
skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
}
\makeatother

\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}

\newtheorem{thm}[mydef]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[mydef]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{test}

\begin{df}[mytitle={Pythagorean Theorem, See~\cite[page 6]{test}}]
test text
\end{df}

\begin{thm}[See~\cite{test}]
test theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
test proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test} Test
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite an elegant solution but it works. I just defined a new citing command so that the citation is a bit further to the right in the frametitle. So it's something like this:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsthm}


    \newcounter{mydef}[chapter]
    \renewcommand\themydef{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{mydef}}

    \makeatletter

    \def\mdf@mytitle{}
    \define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
      \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}

    \mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}

    \tikzset{
    excursus line/.style={%
    line width=2pt,
draw=gray!40,
rounded corners=2ex,
},
excursus head/.style={%
fill=white,
font=\bfseries\sffamily,
text=blue!80,
anchor=base west,
},
}
\mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
extra={\stepcounter{mydef}},%
singleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
\path [excursus line]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
($(Q)+(30em,0ex)$);
%\node at ($(M)$) {M};
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef\space(\mdf@mytitle):};
\fi},
firstextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,-to]
(O) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-2pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef\space(\mdf@mytitle):};
\fi},
secondextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,round cap-]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
middleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow]
(O) -- (Q);},
middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
hidealllines=true,topline=true,
innertopmargin=0.5ex,
innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innerleftmargin=2ex,
skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
}
\makeatother

\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}

\newtheorem{thm}[mydef]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[mydef]{Proposition}

\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\black{\hspace{30pt}\cite[#1]{#2

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{test}

\begin{df}[mytitle={Pythagorean Theorem \mycite{Definition 3}{test}}}]
test text
\end{df}

\begin{thm}[See~\cite{test}]
test theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
test proposition
\end{prop}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test} Test
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```